# (GCS) Additional permissions required to view this object's metadata: Ask an object owner to grant you 'storage.objects.get' permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, access-control, google-iam, google-bucket

When I clicked the names of the files to see the details with the access control **"Fine-grained"** on **Cloud Storage**:

[image]

I could see the details:

[image]

However, after changing the access control **"Fine-grained"** to **"Uniform"**:

[image]

I couldn't see the details of the files and got this error:

[image]

> Additional permissions required to view this object's metadata: Ask an
> object owner to grant you 'storage.objects.get' permission (e.g., by
> giving your account the IAM Storage Admin role).

Are there any ways to solve the error to see the details of the files with the access control **"Uniform"**?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the error to see the details of the files with the access control **"Uniform"**.

First, open the left side bar:

[image]

Then, click on **"IAM"** from **"IAM & Admin"**:

[image]

Then, click on **"✏️"** to edit the principal's permissions where the role is **"Owner"**:

[image]

Now, one panel is open:

[image]

Next, click on **"ADD ANOTHER ROLE"**:

[image]

Next, choose **"Storage Admin"** from **"Cloud Storage"** **OR**:

[image]

Choose **"Storage Object Admin"** which is more specific **OR**:

[image]

Choose **"Storage Object Viewer"** which is even more specific:

[image]

This time, I choose **"Storage Admin"** and click on **"SAVE"**:

[image]

Finally, you can solve the error and see the details of the files with the access control **"Uniform"**. *Don't forget that the change of the principal's permissions is reflected after **a little time**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the possible explanation for this behavior is that you might not have enough permissions on the bucket level, as you can see that the [uniform access control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-uniform-bucket-level-access#prereqs) uses bucket-level permissions, whereas fine-grained access control uses object-level permissions. Thus, you should check your bucket-level permissions if it is having `storage.buckets.get` IAM permissions.

If you go through [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access#overview) you will find the below statement like I explained above.

> If you enable uniform bucket-level access, you revoke access from
> users who gain their access solely through object ACLs and prevent
> users from administrating permissions using bucket ACLs. Be sure that
> you read considerations when migrating an existing bucket prior to
> enabling uniform bucket-level access.

You can refer [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) to know how to add IAM permissions to a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the error to see the details of the files with the access control **"Uniform"**.

The easiest way is change back the access control **"Uniform"** to **"Fine-grained"** again:

[image]

Then, again, change back the access control **"Fine-grained"** to **"Uniform"** but don't forget to check **"Add project role ACLs to the bucket IAM policy"** :

[image]

Finally, you can solve the error and see the details of the files with the access control **"Uniform"**.

[image]